# java.net.ConnectException in Android Widget on correct public URL only in 4G mode (wifi ok)

Tags: java, android

My code (is an Android widget):

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
  //...
    
  protected RequestResult doInBackground(String... params) {
    //...
    final String requestAddress = "http://something.mydomain.cz:8080/somefile.xml"; // is correct, publicly accessible and working
    try {
      Log.i("WIDGET", "Request address: " + requestAddress);
      URL url = new URL(requestAddress); // <- exception here
      //...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Log.e("WIDGET", "Request error: " + ex.toString());
      //...
    } finally {
      //...
    }
    //...
  }  

  //...
}
```

This code normally worked both in 4G/wifi, but today it suddenly stopped working when connected via 4G.
In the console it reports following exception:

> I/WIDGET: Request address: http://something.mydomain.cz:8080/somefile.xml

> E/WIDGET: Request failed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to something.mydomain.cz/{domain IP}:8080

Text {domain IP} means IP of mydomain.cz.

Seems like some Android library code (maybe DNS resolver code?) incorrectly adds domain's IP to the URL, when connected via 4G.

My phone uses Android 12 (kernel 4.14.113, UI 4.1).

Clearing app data/memory does not help.

Reinstalling the app does not help.

Phone restart does not help.

Other widgets with Internet communication (eg. weather) work.

Android bug?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, data saver was on.

I forgot it was on, reinstalled the app today, and forgot to reapply data saver exception in the phone settings for it.

Its just curious the Java exception says this error message. I would except something like:

"Cannot connect, data saver is on. Please apply exception for this app in the phone settings."